# Google Play services returns error, "The requested player with ID me was not found"

Tags: php, google-play-services

I have downloaded the sample code from https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples for implementing Google Play services leaderboard.

and downloaded the code from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services for authentication and services

after I logged in with google sign in it shows the following error

> {"status":"failure","message":"{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n
>   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"notFound\",\n
>   \"message\": \"The requested player with ID me was not found.\"\n
>   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 404,\n  \"message\": \"The requested player with
>   ID me was not found.\"\n }\n}\n"}

I changed

```
 require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
 require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_GamesService.php';
```

to

```
require_once '../googleclient/vendor/autoload.php';  in GameHandler.php
```

Also I changed

```
$this->games = new google_GamesService($this->client);
```

to

```
$this->games = new Google_Service_Games($this->client);  in setupApiClient function in GameHandler.php
```

Now I found this line throws the error

```
 $response = $this->games->players->get('me'); in loginUser function in GameHandler.php
```

But I could not find exactly which class and which function

I assume that this is the file

```
 googleclient\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Games\Resource\Players.php
```

In the above file there is function called get, so inside the function I put echo "hi"; die(); in the first line but it is not printed.